# C Finding frequent character from a text file

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, char

I am trying to write a program that takes input a text file and find the most frequent character and how many times. I kept getting 0 for the result. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 FILE *fp;
 char *filename;
 char ch;
 int array[255] = {0};
 char str[]= "";
 int i, max, index;


// Check if a filename has been specified in the command
if (argc < 2)
{
    printf("Missing Filename\n");
    return(1);
}
else
{
    filename = argv[1];
    printf("Filename : %s\n", filename);
 }

 // Open file in read-only mode
 fp = fopen(filename,"r");

  // If file opened successfully, then print the contents
  if ( fp )
  {
    printf("File contents:\n");
    while ( (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
       {
            for (i = 0; i < 255; i++){
        ch = str[i];
  }

// Find the letter that was used the most
for(i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++)
{
 ++array[str[i]];
}
max = array[0];
index = 0;
for(i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++)
{
 if( array[str[i]] > max)
 {
     max = array[str[i]];
     index = i;
  }
 }

 printf("The max character is: %c \n", str[index]);
 printf("The amount is %d\n", max);
       }

   }
else
  {
     printf("Failed to open the file\n");
    }

return(0);
}
```

This is the output from the code: 
Filename : text.txt
File contents:
The max character is:
The amount is 0
The max character is:
The amount is 0
The max character is:
The amount is 0
The max character is:
The amount is 0

Comment: The `for` loop with the condition `str[i] != 0` will be run once as `str[1]` is `0`.

Comment: That first `for` loop won't be run at all (based on initialization values). Why is it there?

Comment: First, indentation is correct.

Comment: Check your close braces `}` carefully. You might be missing one to `for (i = 0; i < 255; i++){`. This part doesn't make sense anyway. You read a character `ch` from the file, then reassign it to something else without using it.

Comment: Also, please learn the habit of correctly indenting and aligning your code. It makes it easier for you to read as you write it, and for others (and yourself) to read later.

Comment: The `for` loop inside `while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)` sets the value in `ch` to 0 for each of 256 iterations.  You never increment `str[i]`.  You should not have the `for` loop there — rethink what you are doing!

Answer (score 1):

`int array[255]` is too small. Range for `unsigned char` is from 0 up to and including 255, so it should be `array[256]`

You simply need to count the occurrences of each character:

```
while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    array[ch]++;
```

Note that `ch` should be declared as `int`, not `char` whose range includes negative numbers. Having declared it as `char` will cause error when reading non-ASCII files. You can cast `ch` back to `(char)` later.

Then find which character is most common:

```
int most_common_char = 0;
for(i = 1; i < 256; i++)
    if(array[i] > array[most_common_char])
        most_common_char = i;
```

I would recommend using hard coded filename for testing, example `const char *filename = "test.txt"`, it will make it easier to debug the code.

Example:

```
int main()
{
    const char *filename = "test.txt";
    FILE *fp;
    int ch;
    int array[256] = { 0 };
    int i;
    int most_common_char;

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(!fp)
    {
        printf("Failed to open the file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        array[ch]++;

    most_common_char = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < 256; i++)
        if(array[i] > array[most_common_char])
            most_common_char = i;

    printf("most common character: %c\n", (char)most_common_char);

    return(0);
}
```